# Any alternative for Directory Monitoring in Windows other than Windows Directory Monitoring

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm using Directory Monitoring in Windows to get File System Notifications. But when i'm working with Large Number of files say 10K files or more, i'm missing Some Delete Notifications. I can't afford to miss delete notifications. But Windows Directory Monitoring is not giving me all notifications properly. It seems to be missing some events.

I just queue the Folders which i need FS notifications ,add Notifications Flags and wait for Notification. I have just did as in this Example, with little modifications.

http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=400&ver=vcpp

Is there any alternative for Directory Monitoring in Windows other than Windows's Own, Something working Perfectly ..? Or am i making any mistakes in my Program , Actually i have checked my Code. I'm pretty sure it's handling all the notifications it's getting.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're doing or, even better, show some code that isn't working as you'd expect. I've never heard of monitoring file system through AD, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt...

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows Directory Monitoring"?  The ReadDirectoryChanges function?  What does it have to do with Active Directory?

Comment: Perhaps this is your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2005/10/07/478396.aspx